# How to format the ListView Headers On maximise

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, format

When I maximise my WPF window, The ListView headers stay in the same position. How would I format it too stretch across the whole screen when maximised.

Minimised: 
[image]

Maximised: 
[image]

What it should look like: 
[image]

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: The column width for a gridview column is a double. You would have to iterate the columns and set widths programmatically. You could try a datagrid instead and use * based widths. Datagrid column width is type gridlength.